# Typescript and IDB library for using indexedDB. Guidance needed

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

Question from a newbie.
I'm trying to follow the walk through [Working with IndexedDB](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) tutorial which uses [Jake Archibald's IDB library](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb) but using Typescript instead of plain Javascript. I'm not having much of a success so far.

My code looks like this.

```
import * as idb from "./idb";

const dbPromise: Promise<idb.DB> = idb.default.open('test-db2', 1, (upgradeDb: idb.UpgradeDB) => {
    console.log('making a new object store');
    if (!upgradeDb.objectStoreNames.contains('firstOS')) {
        upgradeDb.createObjectStore('firstOS');
    }
});
```

The definition file loads well since the compiler doesn't throw any errors and intellisense works fine in VS Code.

I manage to load my module using require.js on my html page, but the console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (main.ts:8)
at Object.execCb (require.min.js:5)
at b.check (require.min.js:5)
at b.<anonymous> (require.min.js:5)
at require.min.js:5
at require.min.js:5
at each (require.min.js:5)
at b.emit (require.min.js:5)
at b.check (require.min.js:5)
at b.enable (require.min.js:5)
```

Now, if I remove `default`from the call to `idb.default.open(...)`, the compiler tells me that 'open' does not exist on type '.../idb'.
The library exports `idb` as its default.

I'm missing some sort of initialization but I cannot really see what or where.

Can anyone help?

**WORK AROUND**

This is how I finally made this work.

```
import * as idxdb from "./idb";
import "./js/idb.js";

let dbPromise: Promise<idxdb.DB> = idb.open('test-db2', 1, (upgradeDb: idxdb.UpgradeDB) => {
    console.log('making a new object store');
    if (!upgradeDb.objectStoreNames.contains('firstOS')) {
        upgradeDb.createObjectStore('firstOS');
    }
});
```

The first import statement brings the types in so it compiles and it provides hinting. The second statement brings the idb object to the mix.

Thanks very much to [@Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2204759/josh) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, not a typescript expert, but after learning some module syntax, it looks like an a module problem. Looking at the code of https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/blob/master/lib/idb.js, you see see that in the browser context the variable idb is defined at the end with `self.idb = exp;`.

So you are trying to import a module using ES6 module syntax, but the file you are importing is not a module, in the sense that it has no exports, and no default export.

(1) You can downoad the idb.js file and insert an export default in there at the end, and proceed with importing the default exported value.

(2) You can learn how to import a script file as a module when it does not export anything.

Under 2, because `self` is `window` in the browser, you probably can just directly access the variable `idb`, because by including the file it becomes defined in global scope.

So, first you want to import the file, ignoring what it exports, using `import "./idb.js"`.  This style of import syntax ignores whatever is exported. Since we know idb.js doesn't export anything, this is great because it is the minimal amount of work needed to import a file without exports.  And the result of the import is that it is evaluated, so that means the imported will declare `idb` in global scope of window as an implied side effect of the module (defining globals is normally frowned upon in modules but this is ok because this is a non-module).

So ... try the following, if you are working in a browser context:

```
import "./idb.js";

// This should print out information about the idb object declared in 
// global scope of the browser (e.g. under window.idb)
console.log(idb); 

// Because the variable idb is basically just a global, just access 
// here as it comes from the global
const dbPromise: Promise<idb.DB> = idb.open(...);
```

Comment: I finally figured it out thanks to your comments! Edited the post in case anyone find himself in the same situation. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

```
import idb from 'idb';
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a default export, the syntax is:

```
import idb from "./idb";
```

This only works with default exports.

You should then be able to use:

```
idb.open(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Fenton. I'm afraid I tried all this. Your first import, causes the whole type hinting to go all red squiggles (event removing idb as its prefix). And, the page still crashes "Cannot read property default". Can this be a requirejs configuration missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be because the idb javascript does not support AMD loaders (such as require.js, which I'm using).

adding the following lines at the end of index-min.js worked for me:

```
)({});
/** added this: */
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "idb", [], function() {
        return { openDB:idb.openDB, deleteDB:idb.deleteDB, wrap:idb.wrap, unwrap:idb.unwrap}
    });
}
```